# Restrict routing per role

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to restrict certain routes and / or change components for any route base on a value such as the logged in user's role?

I want this so an administrator's default page is different to a normal user, but also perhaps to restrict access if the route is set manually in the browser.

Or is it a better solution to have a base component that redirects to another route?

I understand that restricting access via the router does not replace real account security, but would seem like a first good step in preventing users guessing restricted routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great example of implementing authentication and authorization with vue router: https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

Basically you can check premissions before letting user open the protected component. The easiest way to achieve this is using router guards. In your router definitions:

```
{
  path: '/proctected',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      if (!hasPermissionsNeeded(to)) {
        next('/page-to-show-for-no-permission');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next('/page-to-show-for-unauthenticated-users');
    }
  }
}
```

This guard will protect from entering  `/proctected` url. Here you can check the working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwxoMe

Below an example of guard for all routes:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (isAuthenticated()) {
    if (!hasPermissionsNeeded(to)) {
      next('/page-to-show-for-no-permission');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next('/page-to-show-for-unauthenticated-users');
  }
})
```

More about router guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for, and the link really helps also.